# start workflow 13 on event receiver item attached

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow, event-receiver

I am using the same code to trigger 13 workflow form item attachment event receiver ,but i am getting null in (SPWorkflowAssociation associationTemplate) in case of 13 workflow template ,while successfully able to trigger 10 workflow template.

Can u please guide this isssue?.

Comment: can you add a code snippet or example to help clarify your issue as well as any output generated?

Comment: Iam using the above code snippet mention in URL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483446/invoke-sharepoint-workflow-after-eventreceiver